# How can I change data on Firebase without any of my clients running?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, timer, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a web app that uses Firebase and React. I'd like to have a timer in the app that resets once it finishes - my idea was to store the date for the end of the timer in Firebase and then have the client compare the current date to the end of the timer every time it launches. My only issue is that I'm not sure how to push a new end of timer date to Firebase once the current timer finishes. This is something that would need to happen even if none of the clients were running. If the answer is just that I need to have at least one client always running, then I'd appreciate any suggestions on a practical way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your own "client", which fetches the database regularly (up to you to decide the interval) and compares the date of every client to the current date. This is basically what you'd call a backend.

It's up to you to decide which language you use. There are firebase libraries [for some languages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/), otherwise you can use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/). As you already seem to have experience with Javascript, I'd recommend using it (maybe in combination with Node.js, I have no concrete experience with that).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using Node.js, which Firebase had instructions for [on their website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Answer (score 0):

First approach of having a backend service is an option, but I think you can also use Firebase Cloud Functions.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_database_sanitization_and_maintenance

With Cloud Functions you can do a lot of work using triggers. A trigger can be an update on your database, a file sent to your storage or even a HTTP request. In the link below you can see triggers available for realtime database

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Hope it helps.

Comment: I went with the backend solution this time, but I'll have to look into that. Thanks for the advice